# Max no. of piece in k cut

Tags: optimization, algorithms, combinations

Suppose I have large piece of rectangular sheet. Cutting is allowed only vertically and horizontally. 
My approach is

1. if no. of cut is even then max. no of piece is (n/2)*(n/2)
2. if no of cut is odd then max no piece is ((n-1)/2)*((n+1)/2)

I just want to clarify that is this approach correct or there will be some condition where it will fail.

Comment: The [tag:maximum-principle] has nothing to do with your question. Please read the tag description before applying a tag.
Also note that $3$ horizontal cuts and $2$ vertical cuts will yield $4$ rows and $3$ columns of pieces, thus a total of $12$, not $6$.

Comment: @AlexR , will remember next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make $k$ of $n$ cuts horizontally and $n-k$ cuts vertically, the result will be $(k+1)(n-k+1) = -k^2 + n k + (n+1)$ pieces. Maximizing this is equivalent to finding
$$\max_{k\in\{0, \ldots, n\}} -k^2+nk+(n+1)$$
The derivative is $-2k+n$ and the function is concave, thus $k=\frac n2$ is the unique maximum in $\mathbb R$.
If $n$ is even, we are done and have prooved that $k=\frac n2$ is optimal. If $n$ is odd, we use concavity and the symmetry of a parabola around the $y$-axis shifted into the extremum ($f(e+x)=f(e-x)$ if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ and $e$ is the unique extremum) to see that both $k=\frac{n+1}2$ and $k=\frac{n-1}2$ yield optimal solutions.

The resulting maxima are
$$p_\max = \begin{cases} (\frac n2 +1)^2 & n\text{ even}\\ (\frac{n-1}2+1)(\frac{n+1}2 + 1) & n \text{ odd} \end{cases} = \Big(\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor +1\Big)\Big(\lceil \frac n2 \rceil +1\Big)$$